# Matlab Finding All Possible Triangles

Tags: matlab, geometry, spatial, coordinate

I have several datasets and smallest have around 1000 points and largest have around 1,000,000 points. These points are consist of Longitude and Latitude information.

I would like to create triangles for all possible combinations of these points. I am planning to use Matlab. I will appreciate any answer about how to create triplets of points from these datasets by using Matlab.

One other problem is as you can see there are huge number of points in my dataset so how can I find a fast way to do this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want to find all the triangles, or just those that do not contain any other points inside them?

Comment: I want all the triangles. Otherwise I would use delaunay :)

Comment: [`combnk`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/combnk.html) is a (probably) faster Statistics-Toolbox implementation of Matlabs classic [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html). But on [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26190-vchoosek) are several alternatives which are magnitudes faster. You could first try and benchmark them. But apart from that, you will run out of memory and the resulting variable will be too big.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `combnk( points, k);`

http://www.mathworks.in/help/stats/combnk.html

Comment: I know that function but it will be incredibly slow due to high number of points. This is why I am looking for a faster way.

Comment: Well, with  1,000,000  points, there will about 10^18 possible triangles. Even if a computer generates 10^9 triplets per second, it will take a huge amount of time. :)

Comment: @Scorpionidas Maybe you should consider using a different language if performance is an issue and you're dealing with a very large dataset. Have you tried `C++`? Though I can't help you with any specific algorithms available in other languages